# Phonegap jQuery Ajax to invoke a webservice

Tags: android, web-services, jquery, cordova

I was trying to invoke a webservice from phonegap android app using jQuery .ajax
But im getting the response as null .

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: '{continent: "' + $('#txtContinent').val() + '"}',
            url: "http://localhost:60931/Service1.asmx/GetCountries",

```
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {

        alert(response);

        },
        failure: function(msg) {

            $('#result').empty().append(msg);
        }
    });
```

can anyone help me in invoking a web service from phonegap app using jQuery .ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will not work until you implement JSONP for your Webservice.
JSONP lets remote calles happen, because cross-site XHR calls are not permitted by default.

A nice implementation of JSONP for ASP.Net Webservices:

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/adelkhalil/archive/2009/08/14/cross-domain-jsonp-with-jquery-call-step-by-step-guide.aspx

Comment: thanx for the reply...
But in my app i need to access a 3rd party webservice . . . what i have to do in that case. . .??

Comment: @RajeshRs: in this case, they have to provide you with a working interface :)

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "Service1.asmx/GetCountries"
```

Is this service url accessible within the application?